# Increasing, upper bounded sequence of natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let {$A_1, A_2, ...$} a countable family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and let
$$I_1 = A_1$$
$$I_2 = A_1 \cap A_2$$
$$...$$
$$I_k = A_1 \cap ... \cap A_k$$
$$...$$

so that $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq ...$ is an infinite decreasing chain of subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$A \subseteq B \Rightarrow f(A) \geq f(B)\text{ for each }A, B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$$
$$f(\emptyset) = 0$$
$$f(A) \in A \text{ for each }A \neq \emptyset$$

Suppose finally that $\displaystyle \bigcap _i A_i \neq \emptyset$ and let $f(\displaystyle \bigcap _i A_i) = \overline{n}$.

We have $f(I_1) \leq f(I_2) \leq ...$ is an increasing sequence of natural number that is upper bounded by $\overline{n}$.

It is true that this implies the existence of $\overline{k} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for each $j \geq \overline{k}$, $f(A_j) = \overline{n}$?

How can this be formally proved (or disproved)?

Comment: Hint : use the fact that the sequence $(f(I_k))_{k \in \mathbb N}$ approaches $\overline n$ as $k$ tends to $+\infty$ and what it means in terms of epsilons.

Comment: Hi Zag, I'm not sure the statement is true. 
Take this example: define $A_k =$ {$0, 1$} $\cup $ {$n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ : } n \geq k + 1$} and define $f$ as follows: $f(A) = 0$ if $A =$ {$0, 1$} and $f(A) = 1$ if $A$ contains $1$ and at least one element greater than $1$.
Then $\displaystyle \bigcap _i A_i = $ {$0, 1$} and $f(\displaystyle \bigcap _i A_i) = 0$ but $f(I_k) = 1$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Is this a valid counterexample?

Comment: Indeed it seems like a valid counterexemple. Sorry I went to fast and thought that $f(I_k) \underset{k \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} f(\bigcap_i A_i)$ which is not necesserly the case !

Comment: I'm a bit confused on whether or not such an $f$ can exist. It seems the third condition implies that $f(\{a\}) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$. But then this implies that for all $a \in S$, $f(S) \geq f(\{a\}) = a$. For infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, then, this forces $f(S) = \infty$.

Comment: You are right @HaydnGwyn, I made a mistake in the formulation of the question. I had in mind the "min" function, and I wanted to generalize that, but I wrote the wrong symbol in the first property. I'll edit the question

Comment: The properties listed now uniquely identify the min function. As before, we have $f(\{a\}) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$. It follows that for all $a \in S$, $f(S) \leq f(\{a\}) = a$, so $f(S) \leq \min S$. But $f(S) \in S$ as well, so in fact we must have $f(S) = \min S$.

Comment: And this in turn means my counterexample is wrong. So maybe the statement could be true?

Comment: We could prove the result by analyzing the min function directly, noting that if $k=\min \bigcap_i A_i$, then for all $\ell \leq k$, there exists $n_\ell$ such that $\ell \notin A_{n_\ell}$. Setting $n = \max_{\ell} n_\ell$ gives us that $\min I_n = k$ and hence for all $m \geq n$, $\min I_m = k$.

Comment: If you would like to generalize the min function, you could relax or remove the second or third condition on $f$.  It's not immediately clear to me whether or not the claim is true with these relaxed conditions

Comment: If you remove the third condition the claim is not true. For example, you can define $f$ such that $f(A) = 0$ if $A$ is finite and $f(A) = 1$ if $A$ is infinite, and my previous counterexample can be easily be adapted to show an infinite family of infinite sets with finite intersection (over all of them) and infinite intersection (over a finite number of them)